# Git module in Ansible gets permission denied on tmp directory

Tags: git, ubuntu, ansible, devops

I'm trying to clone a remote repository by *Ansible* using the `git` module. Here's the task configuration:

```
- name: Clone repo
  git:
    repo: "{{ repository }}"
    dest: "/home/{{ username }}/abc"
    key_file: "{{ git_key_file }}"
  register: code_update
```

But unfortunately it fails with below error:

```
fatal: [xyz]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/git clone --origin origin '' /home/xyz/abc", "msg": "Cloning into '/home/xyz/abc'...\nfatal: cannot exec '/tmp/tmpm9mfdkci': Permission denied\nfatal: cannot exec '/tmp/tmpm9mfdkci': Permission denied\nfatal: unable to fork", "rc": 128, "stderr": "Cloning into '/home/xyz/abc'...\nfatal: cannot exec '/tmp/tmpm9mfdkci': Permission denied\nfatal: cannot exec '/tmp/tmpm9mfdkci': Permission denied\nfatal: unable to fork\n", "stderr_lines": ["Cloning into '/home/xyz/abc'...", "fatal: cannot exec '/tmp/tmpm9mfdkci': Permission denied", "fatal: cannot exec '/tmp/tmpm9mfdkci': Permission denied", "fatal: unable to fork"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

It is worth mentioning that I can clone repository directly on remote server. Also I tried to change the `TMP` and `TMPDIR` using `environment` setting but nothing changed.

Any response would be appreciated...

Comment: It sure does look like your command contains a blank repository URL, what with `origin '' /home/xyz/abc`; are you sure you're not seeing a downstream error from that misconfiguration?

Comment: I tried to set `version: "master"` and set strict values of variables but nothing has changed. Also still `origin ''` remains.

Comment: Note: this has nothing to do with Git (and only a little to do with Ansible itself, it's a clash between how ansible operates by default, and some security-minded administrator).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`/tmp` at the server is mounted with option `noexec` so `ansible` cannot execute its own temporary scripts. The recommended fix is to set environment variable `TMPDIR`:

```
 - name: Clone the git repo in a temporary directory
      environment:
        TMPDIR: "/home/{{ username }}/tmp"
      git:
        repo: "{{ repository }}"
        dest: "/home/{{ username }}/abc"
        key_file: "{{ git_key_file }}"
```

Make sure the directory exists.

See https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/30064, esp. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/30064#issuecomment-487149251

Comment: Can the above be used during the ansible-pull methode?